# Is there anyway to make Stealth an int based skill?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, skills, stealth

In pathfinder, there are many ways to substitute skills to use other ability modifiers. Is there a way to use intelligence in place of dex for stealth checks?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### There is no way to substitute Int for Dex for stealth checks.

It's hard to prove a negative, but I have not turned up a way to use *any* other ability score in place of Dex for the stealth skill. It's primarily the social skills that can be converted to use other ability scores.

#### There is one way to add Int to stealth checks.

I did find one way to add Int to stealth checks *in addition to* Dex, however: the magus arcana [Arcane Cloak](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/magus/magus-arcana/paizo-magus-arcana/arcane-cloak-su) lets you add your Int modifier to your stealth skill, and also to your bluff skill if you're trying to create a diversion to hide, for 1 minute. This is... probably not a good use of your arcane pool points.